# How to make the calendar event text editable on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar

I'm trying to implement this calendar plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/minusplus/7a7gG/2/

What I can't figure out is how to make the calendar event text editable when it is clicked.

Looking through the [documentation for the plugin](https://github.com/robmonie/jquery-week-calendar/wiki/), I can't find a method to call to edit the event text. The only example that shows how to set the text is upon initialization using a `title` indicator (to set it below to `"Lunch with Mike"`):

```
var eventData = {
    events : [
       {"id":1, 
       "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), 
       "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 35),
       "title":"Lunch with Mike"},
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the event `eventClick` you need to edit the data to store whatever value for the eventData.events.title you want, and then render it again, `$(”#calendar”).weekCalendar(”today”);`

I have never used this plugin, but this is what it looks like you need to do based on how I read the documentation.